# Is there a way to use pg_dump with a query filter on the table?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I would like to export a set of `INSERT` commands with pg_dump. I do not want to dump the full table though. I want to filter the table for specific rows with:

`SELECT * FROM table where col=4`

Is there a way to pass this information to `pg_dump` something like:

```
pg_dump db_name --column-inserts --data-only --table='(SELECT * FROM table WHERE col=5)' > test.sql
```

The above is a pseudo example. It does not really work. But is there such functionality like this without having to create a secondary table with the data out of that query?

Comment: No there is not.